# undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates

Tags: error-handling

symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates.
I am trying to use command line tool pdf2htmlEX  using this line
exec("pdf2htmlEX ".$name) and i get this Error In Ubuntu 22.04.1. Not sure where is the issue. I works fine when i try it using terminal but when i try it in php then the error occurs.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What exactly are you doing when the error is triggered? Some context please. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I had a similar case. Its related to multiple freetype libraries in the system .see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628277/libcairo-undefined-symbol-ft-get-var-design-coordinates-error-when-calling-r-fr?rq=1